# How to make JavaFX tell if I'm on a 4k or 1080p screen

Tags: javafx, screen, screen-resolution

I am trying to make JavaFX detect the screen resolution I'm on, either 1080p or 4k, so I can size/position my program accordingly.

I tried `Screen.getPrimary().getDpi()` and it printed "96". Using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()` I got a result of "144". I have no idea which one is right or if there is a better way to do it.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need to "make JavaFX detect the screen resolution I'm on, either 1080p or 4k, so I can size/position my program accordingly". JavaFX will take into account default device output scaling when calculating sizes.  That is, the JavaFX co-ordinate system is based upon the output scaled pixels, not the physical pixels of the display. That way the app will display well scaled regardless of whether a 4K or 1080p display is used.  It'll even be OK if the app window is split halfway between two dissimilar displays.

Comment: My guess is that you get 96 reported as the dpi from JavaFX and 144 as the screen resolution from the AWT Toolkit, because the AWT Toolkit isn't taking into account an [output scale display setting](https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge_wm_brb/public/field/image/2015/08/windows-10-display-settings-desktop-3.png?itok=_5Q6aIps) of 150% which is applied by your OS to scale output onto the given display that you are measuring.  That is, AWT is reporting physical pixel DPI and JavaFX is reporting output scaled DPI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually want to know the the screen **size** and not the pixel **density**. *DPI* is a measurement for [Dots Per Inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).

In JavaFX you achieve this with the [Screen class](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html). As the user named *[jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea)* pointed out the *visual bounds* only return the values for the *visual* area of the selected screen. That means that you want to use `screenObject.getVisualBounds()` for that and `screenObject.getBounds()` for the actual screen sizes.

```
 // full bounds
 Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();

 bounds.getWidth(); // screens width
 bounds.getHeight(); // screens height

 // visual bounds
 Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

 visualBounds.getWidth(); // screens usable width (no task bars etc.)
 visualBounds.getHeight(); // screens usable height
```

In the code snippet the **primary** screen is used. You can also get other screens by using [`Screen.getScreens()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreens()).

Comment: A couple of things to note: [`visualBounds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getVisualBounds--) won't contain "objects in the native windowing system such as taskbars and menu bars", also the `visualBounds` "will be reported relative to this [`outputScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleX--)", so a 4K screen resolution on Windows, might be reported as (3,840x2,160 / output scale factor of 2) - taskbar area (so perhaps something like 1920 x 1000) (my guess from the documentation, I haven't tried it).

Comment: I just tried it on a 2014 15" MacBook Pro with Retina display, and the visual bounds are 1440x805, versus the native display resolution of 2880x1800.

Comment: @jewelsea I will definitely add this to the answer to clarify. It is of course wanted behavior because the usable area is what you want to account for and OP asked to *"size/position accordingly"*.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found another way to find the screen width using AWT GraphicsEnvironment. The code is following:

```
     GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode().getWidth()
```

This method gives me the "true" 4k screen width: 3840

Using the following method in Javafx, the width is 2560.

```
Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
```

Thought might be an useful information to put out there for people encountering the similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I see jewelsea's comment mentions this a little, but I'd like to explain recommended render scales further.

DPI can be used to arrive at a metric for Inches, so you could reverse engineer the correct scale for your rendering if you want inches, but the OP asked about identifying a 4K screen from a 1080 screen.

What you may be surprised to learn is that windows can report a screen as scaled up or down according to your display settings scale.

For instance on my 3840x2400 screen, I have scale set to 200%. In some cases windows will report my 4k screen as 1920x1200, being the real resolution divided by my 200% scale.

[JavaFX Screen.getOutputScaleX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleX--)

In JavaFX if you call Screen.getScreens() and investigate such a screen, you will find that the Screen object includes outputScale X and Y fields representing display scale as a double. Here it is 2.0. All my JavaFX rendering occurs with that scale natively. If I render a 10 pixel square on the screen with a 200% ui scale, it will actually draw 20 pixels on the screen, rendering it 200% larger. Ultimately this makes drawing on different screens by pixels look more uniform if the UI scale is set to achieve a similar information density on each screen, though I found it to be a headache to account for in more advanced rendering.

So if you want rendering that appears the same in pixel count on any screen, divide your draw calls by the outputScale. If you want them the same in inches, divide by DPI.

If you would like to identify whether a screen is truly 4K regardless of outputScale.

```
private boolean is4K(Screen screen){
    return screen.getVisualBounds().getWidth() * screen.getOutputScaleX() > 3500;
}
```