# Force JavaFX Hi-DPI mode to be enabled

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, retina-display, retina

Is there a way to "force" JavaFX to enable the Hi-DPI mode? Maybe through some specific VM-argument or something? This would be highly useful for debugging/testing an application without having access to a respective display.

This question already covers the basics about JavaFX 8's Hi-DPI mode pretty well, but it doesn't give any way of "enforcing" the mode to be active: [JavaFX 8 HiDPI Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182460/javafx-8-hidpi-support/26184471?s=4|0.3364#26184471)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using:

```
-Dprism.allowhidpi="true"
```

as a command line option, or calling:

```
System.setProperty("prism.allowhidpi", "true");
```

at the beginning of your application?

I can't test it on Windows, but on Android (JavaFXPorts) it works when is set as a property in a custom properties file (by default is true, this will disable it):

```
prism.allowhidpi=false
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions, but unfortunately they don't seem to change anything... I'm using OS X Yosemite if this makes any difference...

Comment: Can you post what `-Dprism.verbose="true"` gives you? On Windows, I've noticed that with `-Dprism.allowhidpi="false"` I get `Not opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling`, while `-Dprism.allowhidpi="true"` gives `Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling`.

Comment: I get the same output. Interestingly I also get `Opting in for HiDPI scaling` when I don't set `allowhidpi` flag. I guess this only _allows_ JavaFX to use HiDPI scaling, not _forces_ it to use it!?

Comment: So by default JavaFX will try to use Hi-DPI by default, but as you say, it doesn't force it. Maybe you have to simulate it on your display (check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on)).

Comment: Thanks!! Tested successfully on Windows10 with a DELL XPS-13 and QHD screen, but I setted it to "false" to let Windows10 do the scaling instead of JAVAFX

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 this JVM argument worked for me (Java 8u102) and is necessary to auto scale with all dpi settings. The minimal setting to activate Hi DPI is set to 1 (100%). Without this setting the 125% dpi setting in Windows 7 will not auto-scale, while 150% and 200% will:

```
-Dglass.win.minHiDPI=1
```

In an JavaFX [Ant deploy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#A1321122) the above setting can be applied like this:

```
<fx:deploy
   <fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
       <fx:property name="glass.win.minHiDPI" value="1"/>
   </fx:platform>
</fx:deploy>
```